# What is a rational bubble? What are some well known models for rational bubble?

Tags: macroeconomics

Rational bubble is a situation in which price of asset exceeds its fundamental value and people are buying the overpriced asset because they think that they can sell it for higher in the future. Is this correct?

What are some well known models for rational bubble?